What is the thin pipe (looks like PVC) under the kitchen sink?
I have a straight thin pipe coming out of the wall under kitchen sink, similar to the one in the picture circled in red. As there is already a bigger drain pipe under the sink, this thin pipe seems to be something else. My house is built in 90s. Does anyone know what the pipe is for?

Thanks
Bing

water softener connection

Do you have a similar pipe in the location for your refrigerator, perhaps an easy connection for an ice maker.
